# How to extract or access stream to specific file in gzip using SharpZipLib?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

How to extract specific file (or have streamed access) from tar.gz (tar files and folders and then gzipped) using SharpZipLib? Or maybe anyone has some similar library to do that in .NET cf 3.5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
using ( FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead ( aPackage ) )
{
    using ( GzipInputStream gzStream = new GzipInputStream ( inputStream ) )
    {
        using ( TarInputStream tarStream = new TarInputStream ( gzStream ) )
        {
            TarEntry entry = tarStream.GetNextEntry();
            while ( entry != null )
            {
                if ( entry == theOneIWant )
                {
                    tarStream.CopyEntryContents (outputStream );
                    break;
                }
                entry = tarStream.GetNextEntry();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How could you identify the "theOneIWant" entry?  I thought you would have to find it by name, is there another way? :)

Comment: @Vijay by using any of the properties of TarEntry, which most likely would be Name (or File.) Can't make it too easy now, can I? :D

Comment: What is the outputStream here? how is it initialized?

Comment: @SarangBorude outputStream could be any stream you can write to, either a memory stream or a file stream.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```
public static void Main(string[ args)
{
    TarInputStream tarIn = new TarInputStream(new FileStream(@args[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
    TarEntry curEntry = tarIn.GetNextEntry();
    while (curEntry != null)
    {
        if (curEntry.Name.EndsWith("foo.txt", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            byte[] outBuffer = new byte[curEntry.Size];
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"foo.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
            tarIn.Read(outBuffer, 0, (int)curEntry.Size);
            bw.Write(outBuffer,0,outBuffer.Length);
            bw.Close();
        }
        curEntry = tarIn.GetNextEntry();
    }
    tarIn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example how to parse `TarEntry` within streams in addition to the original answer. This one can replicate hierarchy of empty folders or skip it

```cs
const string prefix = "./"; // sometimes when it comes from Linux
...
// using (.. here
...

TarEntry entry = tarStream.GetNextEntry();
while (entry != null)
{

    string? fileOrFolder;
    if (entry.Name.StartsWith(prefix))
        fileOrFolder = Path.Combine(outDir, entry.Name.Substring(prefix.Length));
    else
        fileOrFolder = entry.Name;

    if (entry.IsDirectory)
    {
        if (createEmptyDirs)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(fileOrFolder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(fileOrFolder);
        }
    }
    else
    {

        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileOrFolder);

        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileOrFolder, FileMode.Create))
        {
            tarStream.CopyEntryContents(fileStream);
            tarStream.Flush();
            fileStream.Flush();
        }
    }

    entry = tarStream.GetNextEntry();

.........
// close usings here
.........
```